# How do i buffer an image from external link

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a external link with an image which i want to stream, but i get this error when i try.

error
"URI formats are not supported."

I tried to stream:
Stream fileStream = new FileStream("http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-2.jpg", FileMode.Open);
byte[] fileContent = new byte[fileStream.Length];

can anyone put some light on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileStream doesn't support the opening files over the internet.

Try this:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
using(var fileStream = webClient.OpenRead("http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-2.jpg")) 
{
    byte[] fileContent = new byte[fileStream.Length];       
}
```

Comment: i have tried this as it looked simple but this doesnt work. i get following error: "This stream does not support seek operations."

Comment: i tried again with little modification and it works as well. great stuff.  instead of streaming complete path, i take the Image part of it like in above example:                                                               Image pic = Image.FromStream(fileStream);

Answer (score 4):

The FileStream contructor you are using must be provided with a path on your local harddrive and not with an external URL.

You are probably looking for this:

```
string url = "http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-2.jpg";
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();
```

Probably also for this:

```
Image pic = Image.FromStream(stream);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pic.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
Byte[] arr = ms.ToArray();
```

Comment: wow this really works. does this mean the picture will be saved temporary?

Comment: It won't be temporary saved on the harddrive. You can probalby get the byte[] from the Stream Object. I posted the second code snippet to show you, how you have access to manipulating the image. You can insert you image resizing algorithm (google for c# resize image) there.

Comment: hi thanks, this was really handy.  i got into another problem with having access to the file. the network which i am accessing is internal link which needs credentials. so i added a line for that which i want to share. httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential
            {
                UserName = username,
                Password = passowrd,
                Domain = domain
            };